# Anybody know of a good guide or link about moving the search control from the SharePoint Search Center to the navigation bar on a site?

Tags: search

I have created a search center on my firm's intranet site.  Now I've been tasked with moving the search control from the search center to the v4 master page to replace the control that has "Search this site."

I've found a lot of stuff about moving that search control somewhere else, but nothing about moving the search control from the search center to the navigation area.

I'd appreciate any links, resources or ideas...

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you might want to do this, instead of configuring your site to use the enterprise search controls?

Comment: Unless you use advanced search, the search box just pass the search keywords as query string to results page. You can have a plain html textbox and button with some script.

Comment: Not sure how I would configure the site to use enterprise search controls?

Comment: Andy summed it up pretty well

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, you can't 'Move' the control.

Secondly, the search control that's showing the 'Search This Site' link, in the top right of your pages, is quite configurable. Go to Site Collection Settings > Search Settings. You probably want to change the dropdown mode to something else, if you're wanting to get rid of the 'Search this site' type links (this is a "contextual search).

Finally, if that doesn't do it for you, that search box shown on the pages in the site is actually a delegate control - the SmallSearchInputBox - so you could create your own delegate control feature to override it with something else, if that's what you want.

I did [a little of this in 2007](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/01/10/changing-the-smallsearchinputbox-delegate-control/). I don't think it's changed much.

Comment: The control in the search center is a web part, if you _really_ want to you can export the web part and embed it directly into your masterpage. Andy's solution is the more elegant/correct approach though